# Add subdomain to AWS Route 53 from hostinger

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a working domain in my hostinger, I want to deploy react apps in AWS amplify so I dont want to point entire domain to AWS instead I want to point a subdomain like app.domain.com from hostinger to AWS.  How is this possible? What all DNS entries should I make?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is called subdomain delegation. The official Route53 documentation for that is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html).

The general steps are:

1. Create a Route53 hosted zone for the subdomain, and view the NS records.
2. Get the name servers for your Route 53 hosted zone from the AWS console.
3. Update your primary DNS server with NS records for the subdomain, that use the name server values from Route53.

Comment: For step 3, it doesn't seem like Hostinger supports this? When I try to add a NS record, Hostinger gives an error that says "Resource record type is invalid, unsupported or immutable!"

Comment: @treble_maker sounds like you should post a separate question focused on Hostinger DNS. I've never used it so I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to change the A and AAAA records from hostinger account directly.

1. check your instance ipv4 and ipv6 in AWS console
2. login to hostinger and go to DNS zone editor
3. Change your subdomain A record with ipv4 and AAAA record with ipv6

I tried it and it's all worked fine.